# Loops in commutative diagrams

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have some questions on the definition of commutative diagrams.

- Are loops legal in commutative diagrams? If so, does the commutative diagram below imply $i\circ h \circ g \circ f = 1_A$?
- Is it true the 'empty path' from $A$ to $A$ in a commutative diagram represents the identity $1_A$?

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B\\
@A{i}AA @VV{g}V \\
C @<{h}<< D
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Consider the category $\mathrm{Set}$ with $A=B=C=D=\{0,1\}$ and $i=f=g=h$ where $i(0)=i(1)=0$. So the CD holds but $ihgf$ is not the identity.

Comment: The commutative diagrams one encounters in papers generally do not have directed cycles ("loops"). Actually, there is no formal definition of "diagram" or "commute", but to the extent that one can be inferred from actual usage, directed cycles are not permitted in a commutative diagram.

Comment: @ZhenLin I often read that a diagram commutes iff given any two objects any two paths through the diagram have the same result. In this sense I think a cycle should contract to the identity... Of cause it is sometimes useful to draw diagrams with nontrivial loops, but then I would not call it commutative...